# What is the default Window title font in Unity Desktop?

Tags: unity, 13.10, ubuntu-font-family

I have installed unity in my Ubuntu Gnome installation and using Unity Tweak Tool to customize.

What is the default window title font in Unity?

(I have changed everything else)

Comment: It's: ubuntu Bold 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a screen of "**Ubuntu tweak**" tool for font space settings.

[image]

Also, you may use below command to reset fonts back to its default.

```
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/document_font_name
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/font_name
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
```

**Command Source:** [Default Window Title Font](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=454303)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the window title font it's Ubuntu Bold 11

If you use Myunity you can easily check and change

[image]